# Question showing as asked today

Tags: bug

[How do I set the credentials flag to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951502/how-do-i-set-the-credentials-flag-to-false)

I asked that question yesterday, it's showing `asked: today`.

I thought it may have been a difference in timezones, but no timezone is 14 hours+ into today (asked 14 hours ago).

It's no big problem, but it's inaccurate.

Here's were somebody comes out and points something glaringly obvious that I've missed (I had to ask though).

[image]

EDIT: Same with one of my other previous questions: [What basic component am I missing from my signalR client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944816/what-basic-component-am-i-missing-from-my-signalr-client)

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, and when it was asked is based on 24 hours as oppoosed to calendar day. i.e. it was asked less than 24 hours ago so it's still within the same day.

Comment: It *was* asked yesterday. There is no doubt about it. It is 11am on the 15th, UTC. It was asked 8pm on the 14th, UTC. So, yeah. I fail to see the glaringly obvious as well. =D

Comment: I've edited an image into your question.

Comment: Not a bug, but [meta-tag:status-bydesign].  Those timestamps are relative.  It was asked within the last 24 hours, hence it is today

Comment: I asked a similar question on Stack Exchange a while back too, come to think of it. ["Member for: today"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173038/member-for-today).